# With what component I can display the View for set hour and minute?

Tags: android

I want to display the next view but I don´t know what component I should use.
[set hour and minute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koYc3.png)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use time picker for more info visit this site

http://www.journaldev.com/9976/android-date-time-picker-dialog

Answer (score 0):

Use a time picker with timePickerMode attribute equals to clock:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#timePickerMode